# Ipad app: Need uploaded images to go into "Gallery" as well as "Media Library"

Tags: gallery, images

When I upload an image on my desktop, the image is added to

- Media Library
- Gallery

Media Library shows all images that have been uploaded to date, while Gallery only shows images which are associated with this Post.

Using the Wordpress ipad app, however, the image **only appears in the Media Library**.

Is there any way to get new images uploaded to appear in the **Gallery** as well as the **Media Library**?

---

I need this functionality because I have a function which creates a nice javascript gallery from the items in the **Gallery**, and the users of the site are not HTML-aware.

---

I would be happy to get answers that include a different blogging or image app that will do this for me.

Comment: This is better asked in the iOS forums as this is a user-specific and not a development question. http://ios.forums.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 1):

This has been brought up on the iOS WordPress app forum. There appears to be a fix there but the issue is to do with the core of WordPress so switching to another app that publishes via XMLRPC will suffer the same issues. There are a few core trac tickets going on to so this is being looked into.

http://ios.forums.wordpress.org/topic/attachments-post_parent?replies=9#post-823